# Chrome continuously crashes

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using a fairly new Lenovo y700 ideapad with Windows 10.  Every time I use Google Chrome, Chrome loads the landing page properly.  However, when I enter a URL and the browser tries to load the page, the process crashes and I get a message saying Chrome isnt responding.

When I close the crashed Chrome browser, the processes (7 or so) still run in the background.  When I try to end all the processes, the last process is unable to stop.  I tried stopping it through command line using taskkill but it says "The process chrome.exe with PID 2772 could not be terminated.  Reason: There is no running instance of the task".

In the state of having the last remaining process running, I am unable to use any other browser (Tor, Edge, and IE).  The only way to fix it is to reboot.

I've tried reinstalling Chrome and rebooting but that hasn't helped.  I don't think it's a problem with the internet connection as I can ping websites while Chrome is crashed.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Go to advanced settings disable "Continue running background apps" and "hardware acceleration"

Comment: Could be plugins, RAM, CPU, corrupted system, or hard drive issue. Is any of your hardware overclocked? I found that overclocking my RAM on my desktop too much causes Chrome and Windows 10 to crash. You might also want to refresh your Windows installation by following the directions [here](https://www.onmsft.com/news/windows-10-reset-refresh-windows-10-installation-better-performance).